# OpenSea - Set fix price on contract

Tags: nft, contract-invocation, opensea, price

I need to set fix price for an NFT on OpenSea programmatically.

How can I set a price for an NFT of a collection by interacting with the OpenSea contract and what is the OpenSea contract address on Arbitrum?

Comment: can you elaborate on 'interacting with the OpenSea contract'?

Answer (score 0):

Opensea marketplace contract does not store someone's NFT price but their backend.

Being said this, I suggest that you take a look at [Opensea Api](https://docs.opensea.io/v2.0/reference) docs; They do have apis to set up listing with your prices, make auctions, make offers and more;

There are multiple apis that can fullfill your needs;

Comment: Thank you very much @Casareafer for your answer. Yes, it seems to be possible to list NFTs programmatically using the API or SDK. I have a collection wich each NFT on a different address. Unfortunately, an API key is attached to exactly one address. Is there a way to list those NFTs each on a different address using the API or SDK?